# Windows 10 October 2018 Update Wiped GRUB + GRUB Can't Be Repaired or Installed on fresh Ubuntu Installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows-10

I have a laptop using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 LTS.

Yesterday I updated my Windows 10 via Windows10Upgrade Assistant.

After this process, my dual boot is gone.

I tried to re-install grub to recover my Ubuntu using `boot-repair` as suggested here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Nothing worked.

Finally I tried to do a fresh install of Ubuntu (wiping out old Ubuntu) hoping it can fix but `GRUB ERROR` occurred during installation process.

Seems like new update doesn't like any dual boot system.

Any suggestion on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? If BIOS, major Windows updates "forget" to rewrite the Linux partitions into partition table. You then just need to repair partition table. Is fast start up off in Windows? Are you installing in same boot mode as Windows? Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues. Use ppa in Ubuntu live installer and post link it gives.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Use gparted and delete all the partitions especially windows. If efi create a gpt/efi partition and install ubuntu.

Comment: Once again I tried the boot-repair and here is the URL provided http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3XxwqKzpPW/

Comment: Windows: `UEFI`, `Fast start` was `ON` but didn't affect dual boot on previous version. I have tried disabling Fast Startup now after update but error persists with GRUB repair or on fresh Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 2):

I too lost GRUB after Windows 10 Oct 2018 update. (My machine is a Lenovo Yoga 720 laptop.)
After trying a few things, I found the following simple solution:
I pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter BIOS and changed the boot sequence to Ubuntu on hard disk 1st instead of Windows on hard disk 1st.
When I restarted, I could get back into my original GRUB screen with Ubuntu and Windows boot choices. Both Ubuntu and updated Windows work normally.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another Linux machine, try [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) another [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-persistent-ubuntu-usb-stick-using-mkusb-tool)

1. Download Ubuntu
2. Use mkusb to create a **peristent** USB boot drive.
3. Boot the machine using a persistent option
4. Use gparted to configure a small boot partition (resize a partition if necessary) and right click flag it according to EFI or legacy accordingly.
5. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1 --force` replacing "sda1" with the name of your boot partition.

Edit: [Another possibility](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/apt28-uses-lojax-first-uefi-rootkit-seen-in-the-wild/)

Answer (score 0):

Luckly I have my backup on my external drive. This is how I solved the issue.

1. Removed all the partition
2. Installed windows 10
3. Updated windows
4. Installed Ubuntu

Now I am back to dual boot.

Not sure if `boot-repair` messed up or something else entirely.

Still want to know the fix without re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this from Windows 10 itself. I followed this [guide](http://www.penguintutor.com/news/linux/windows10-update).

The important steps:

> Uncheck fast start-up in **Start > Settings > System > Power & Sleep > Additional Power Settings > Choose what the power buttons do > Change settings that are currently unavailable > Turn on fast start-up (recommended)**

It can be that this already solved the issue. If it didn't follow the following steps. Again from the same guide:

> First check the file name matches the one I have on my computer which
> is `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`.
>
> You can't view EFI directly in Windows Explorer etc., so instead right
> click on the Windows logo and choose: Command Prompt (Admin)
>
> Choose a drive letter that isn't in use (I used j: ) and then mount
> the first partition on the disk drive. `mountvol j: /s`
>
> You can then navigate into that drive using: `j: dir`
>
> and cd into the appropriate directories.
>
> Check that there is a file called: `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`. If not then
> you may need to perform the restore from a Ubuntu rescue disk.
>
> If that file does exist then it can be set as the default boot option
> by entering the command `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`